# OkTA SAML integration with React Native

Tags: react-native, single-sign-on, okta

I am developing a react native application. I want to integrate OKTA SAML for SSO(single sign on) in my application. while OKTA official website only provide SDK for Open ID Connect. Is there any way to integrate OKTA SAML SSO in a react native application

Comment: I'm also looking for the same thing, except being disappointed by the less no. of docs that are there on how to achieve this. lmk how u do this.

Comment: Implementing SAML instead of OIDC is like implementing SOAP instead of REST.

Comment: @MattRaible yes you are right but sadly that is the requirement of service provider

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like this one: http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-saml/

Creating a SAML application on Okta is straight-forward: https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Access-Gateway/add-app-saml-pass-thru-add-okta.htm